# Can't execute C executable file

Tags: command-line, c, executable

I'm trying to use libusb for my project, but a mysterious problem occurred.

I compiled the C source code with no errors. It successfully generated an executable C file into the current directory, but when I execute the file a `libusb_init: No such file or directory` error appeared as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @Kulfy yeah, i checked twice the code and it had no logical or syntax error. That's why I'm calling it mysterious problem :) thanks BTW

Comment: I found the prob, as you said it was error in source code. Thanks a lot @Kulfy

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my code. `if` statement was `if(ret <= 0)` and it was conflict with the **libusb_init**

So that's it. The working source code is written below.

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<usb.h>
# include<libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    libusb_device **devs;
    libusb_context *context = NULL;

    size_t list;
    size_t i;
    int ret;

    ret = libusb_init(&context);

    if(ret < 0){
        perror("libusb_init");
        exit(1);
    }

    list = libusb_get_device_list(context,&devs);

    if(list < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "error shuu\n");
        libusb_free_device_list(devs,1);
        libusb_exit(context);
        exit(1);
    }

    int listp = list;

    printf("end %d toxooromj bn\n", listp);

    for(i=0;i<list;i++){
        //print something
    }

    libusb_free_device_list(devs,1);
        libusb_exit(context);

    return 0;
}
```

A special thanks go to @Kulfy for telling me reconsider about check the source code again.